# UTMs and Google's Firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, app-store, utm

I'm having trouble getting my UTM codes recognized in Firebase. All of my data is still flowing in as (not set) even though I have set up my UTMs through Google's developers pages:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#url-builder

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-url-builder

Unfortunately, linking up my Display & Video 360 to Firebase is not an option. Has anyone had any luck in getting the UTMs recognized in Firebase?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use AnalyticsEventCampaignDetails event to set campaign parameter. In that case firebase will attribute to those parameter.